# Scheduler in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, amazon-aurora

I have an Oracle function called by an Oracle Scheduler that resets a sequence everyday. I have to migrate it to RDS Postgres, but AWS doesn't support the extensions pg_cron & pgscheduler. Is there a workaround to do this in RDS Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer is a bit late, but RDS now *does* support `pg_cron` for more recent versions of Postgres. The docs are pretty decent:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/PostgreSQL_pg_cron.html

Here's some good information from Marco Slot, the original author of `pg_cron`:

https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-for-postgresql/evolving-pg-cron-together-postgres-13-audit-log-background/ba-p/1829588